# Inferior Lisp Mode vs Superior Lisp Mode

Tags: major-mode, repl

Can someone explain all the differences in the various lisp modes (inferior, superior, slime, cider)?  Which came first?  Which are extra packages?  What should one use?

Comment: Please clarify which lisp you'd like to use.  If it's common lisp, you're probably going to use `slime`; if it's clojure, then `cider`.  You're unlikely to want to interact directly with `inferior-lisp-mode`, as it's going to be much more bare-bones by comparison (that is, of course, unless you *want* bare-bones).

Comment: I'm looking for which lisp applies to which mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run a process inside Emacs, that process is "inferior" (i.e. a subprocess).

IELM <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>ielm</kbd> is the builtin Inferior Emacs Lisp Mode. It's relatively featureless, but can definitely come in handy. (Esp. for learning Elisp)

[SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), the Superior Lisp Interaction Mode for Emacs, is mostly a joke on the whole "inferior" process name. SLIME is used primarily for Common Lisp (although it can be used with other lisps to varying degrees via extensions). It boasts a large variety of "superior" functions, including debugging, interactive REPLs, and various IDE like functions.

[CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), the Clojure Interactive Development Environment that Rocks for Emacs, is something like SLIME but for Clojure. (Clojure itself being a rather curious lisp that needs some extra work to interface with)

Comment: Does using C-x C-e send to the proper mode depending on file type?

Comment: @JustinThomas not really sure what you mean, I don't run any of these myself.

Comment: Basically C-x C-e evaluates a lisp expression, was wondering if you are in a file of type .clj (clojure) and use it if it evaluates the clojure code--seems to be that it does.  My cider is just broken, which is part of my confusion.

Comment: @JustinThomas that may belong in a new question.

Comment: You probably want to add Emacs Lisp interpreter (IELM) as another bullet point. `C-x C-e` in programming modes, is typically bound to sending the preceding expression to the interpreter for that language, and, in particular, this is true for Emacs Lisp, where Emacs itself acts as an interpreter.

Comment: @JustinThomas Yes, `C-x C-e` will work in SLIME, CIDER, and also Geiser (for Guile/Chicken/Racket Scheme), and others.

Comment: @PythonNut You seen hy yet? Clojurey lisp for Python... https://github.com/hylang/hy

Comment: @24HrRevengeTherapist I have not, but that looks ridiculously awesome.

Comment: @PythonNut Yeah, I am using it for data science and it works as well as Python. The community is super nice and listens to feedback if you have any.

Comment: Note that the Scheme equivalent of these tools is [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/).